# Apple.se and meta.apple.se sites showing as "Android" Operating System power users in welcoming screen.

Tags: bug, status-completed

Am not sure what happened to Apple.se website and it's Meta websites, both are showing as **Android Operating System power users.**

These messages are showing when a user didn't login to the website.

Here are the screenshots.

**Apple.SE**

[image]

**Meta Apple.SE**

[image]

Somebody please correct this ?

Comment: It's also on our [/about](http://apple.stackexchange.com/about) page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed

Comment: would there be a chance to know what happened ?

Comment: @Garikapati apparently someone at StackExchange has been eating too much Bacon.

Comment: @Martin Lol. But if any of Stackexchange team would let us know about what happened, then it's good to know.. stuff ;-)